# Rounding a value of php is different from VB(Visual basic)

Tags: php, vb6, rounding

I am converting a vb application into php application It is all about financing.
In that, I am getting an issue; actually the way of rounding the values in php is different from vb application.

We are storing the values of 14 accounts and distribution amount. In this 5 of them are having 0.01 discrepancies.
We have given below a table of 14 accounts with their distribution amount.

•         Account Number

•         Before applying round function, Actual value of distribution amt

•         Distribution Amount Rounding in VB

•         Distribution Amount Rounding in PHP

[image]

From that we can see the value of 0.01 discrepancy is occurring due to the conflict behaviour of round function between VB and PHP. How to resolve this issue, I need the same amount as like VB.

Comment: VB6 used Bankers Rounding

Comment: What are you using to round in VB6? It doesn't natively have a method to round to X decimal points.

Comment: After rounding value, just dividing it by 100

Comment: Rounding with what? `Int`? `CInt`? `Fix`? assigning to an integer? They all have different rules too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the fraction is .5 VB6 is rounding to nearest even whereas PHP is rounding up.

For the [`round`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php) function in PHP there is an optional third parameter, `mode`, which defaults to `PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP` - you want `PHP_ROUND_HALF_EVEN`.

Example:

```
echo round(29.205, 2, PHP_ROUND_HALF_EVEN); // 29.2
```

See php.net documentation for more information on the `mode` parameter.

Comment: PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP is the third argument, the second is the precision

Comment: @Ray, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP or PHP_ROUND_HALF_EVEN?

Comment: @einterview scratch my last comment... the optional third parameter 'mode' should be PHP_ROUND_HALF_EVEN (the default is PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP)

Comment: Can I know, PHP round based on which algorithm? Like VB6 Round using Bankers Reouding.

Comment: Unlike 'round half to even' which seems to have a large number of different names, 'round half up' seems to be referred to as just that or alternatively 'round half towards positive infinity'. See Wikipedia article on rounding for different types of rounding and their names: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Tie-breaking

Answer (score 0):

You will probably find the old [How To Implement Custom Rounding Procedures](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/196652) useful for understanding things and taking the appropriate action.